# Sketch the Resonance structure

Tags: everyday-chemistry

What are the resonance structure of thioformate ion and  selenocyanat ion?
Give the structure of each resonance? 
With formal charge?

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen from the periodic table below, oxygen, sulphur, and selenium belong to the same group, and they are all non-metals, so one should expect their chemical properties to be similar.

[image]

---

Having established their chemical similarity, one can transform the two ions in question into more familiar forms.

In thioformate anion ($\ce{HCSO-}$), we are not too familiar with sulphur $\ce{S}$, so let us transform it into the more familiar oxygen $\ce{O}$ whose chemical properties are similar. Then, it becomes formate ion ($\ce{HCOO-}$), whose resonance structure is well-known:

[image]

Just transform one oxygen back to sulphur and we are done:

[image]

---

In selenocyanate anion ($\ce{[SeCN]-}$), we are not too familiar with selenium $\ce{Se}$, so let us transform it into the more familiar oxygen $\ce{O}$ whose chemical properties are similar. Then, it becomes cyanate ion ($\ce{[OCN]-}$), whose resonance structure is well-known:

[image]

Just transform the oxygen back to selenium and we are done:

[image]

---

Copyright issues:

- The first image is copyrighted by Michael Dayah.
- The second image is from Wikipedia.
- The third image is a derivative work of the second image.
- The fourth image is taken by [HGTCChem](https://www.flickr.com/photos/99701234@N02/).
- The fifth image is a derivative work of the fourth image.

Answer (score 0):

Thioformate ion is stabilized by resonance but I am not sure about selenocyanat ion.

[image]

Comment: I think the selenocyanat**e** ion is right.

Comment: It is just like cyanate: http://www.cureffi.org/media/2015/01/cyanate-vs-fulminate.png